# Continuity and partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I know that at a point multivariate function can be not continuous, but still have a partial derivative. But what about the interval? If the multivariate function is continuous on some interval $I$, then does it imply that it has a partial derivative w.r.t its some component on that whole $I$. If not, can you please give a counterexample, please?

Edited:
I think giving an example will make my point clear:
$$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & \text if \ (x, y)\in\mathbb{R^2-(0, 0)}\\ 0 & \text if \ (x, y) = (0, 0) \\ \end{cases}$$

In the textbooks, when it finds partial derivative w.r.t $x$ for interval $\mathbb{R^2-(0, 0)}$, it directly finds partial derivative by using quotient rule for one variable without using the limit definition. My question is how do we know, on that interval, a partial derivative exists for all points, therefore we can directly use the quotient rule.

Comment: My position on this problem is that "multivariate function is continuous on some interval I" is weird...

Comment: Take your favorite single variable function that is continuous but not differentiable on an interval. If you call it "a multivariate function that doesn't depend on the other variable", does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if }(x, y)\in\mathbb{R^2-(0, 0)}\\ 0 & \text{if }(x, y) = (0, 0) \\ \end{cases}\text{.}$$

Then for $a\ne 0$ and any $b$, we have $(a,b)\ne 0$, so that a small box around $(a,b)$ can avoid $(0,0)$. For instance, the box could have opposite corner points at $(a/2,b+1)$ and $(3a/2,b-1)$. For all $(x,y)$ inside of that box, $f(x,y)=\dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$.

We can define $g(x)=f(x,b)=\dfrac{2bx}{x^2+b^2}$ for $x$ between $a/2$ and $3a/2$. Note that the definition of $\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(a,b)}$ is the same as $g'(a)$, so all single-variable calculus rules like the quotient rule can be used on $g$ to find that partial derivative.